# Emscripten compile error

Tags: compiler-errors, datamapper, emscripten

I recently just started with emscripten and have run into this error whenever I try to compile something using it. It seems to be working even with error. It generates code that runs just fine in my browser, so I'm not sure if I should worry about it.

Here is the error:

```
/home/jrkirby/emscripten/tools/source-maps/sourcemapper.js:156
    fs.appendFileSync(fileName, '//@ sourceMappingURL=' + path.basename(mapFil
       ^

TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'appendFileSync'
    at appendMappingURL (/home/jrkirby/emscripten/tools/source-maps/sourcemapper.js:156:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jrkirby/emscripten/tools/source-maps/sourcemapper.js:205:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:39)
```

For now, I'm not worrying about it because everything works fine. But I would like to understand why it prints out an error, and how to fix it.

Comment: Maybe your version of node.js is too old? https://github.com/google/pepper.js/wiki/Getting-Started seems to suggest so.